# Why does Clariel not use the tin goblet?

Tags: old-kingdom

In Chapter 18 of Garth Nix's *Clariel*, the titular character is trying to find a tool that will help her create footholes in the prison wall.

> Clariel sat down again and thought about a tool for picking mortar. It would need to be metal, and there was nothing metal in the chamber. (Pg 212, Clariel, Kindle Edition)

However, only a few pages before, Clariel lists the things that are in the prison.

> There was the bed, a simple chest at its foot, and a small table [...]. There was an earthenware pitcher on the table, with a tin goblet next to it, and a lidded chamber pot under the table. (Pg 209, Ibid.)

So there was something metal in the chamber: the tin goblet. This seems like an obvious contradiction, but in the next chapter, Clariel takes a drink several times - so the character (or the author!) haven't forgotten about the goblet.

Is there something that means a) the original quote does not intentionally discount the goblet, or b) the properties of tin goblets make them clearly inadequate for the task.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is the author's mistake - she could easily be drinking out of the jug later on, and she even reiterates that the jug, the chamber pot and the chamber pot's lid are all earthenware later on, but doesn't mention the goblet.

Comment: @Showsni This was my thought too. Fortunately, Journeyman Geek's answer provides a logical explanation even if it was an oversight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tin is an incredibly soft material - we traditionally use tin pots for cooking in my culture and they dent if you look at them funny, melt if you don't pay attention...

'Pure' tin, or a high tin alloy (so not say bronze) is pretty much almost as bad as lead for making tools, and its possible that trying to scratch a hole in a wall will result in tin stains on the wall rather than a hole

Comment: Plus you no longer have anything to drink out of,

Comment: Well if you got *out* that would be less of an issue

Comment: That can take quite a while; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_from_Alcatraz_(film)